# Logback JSON write object to root of log

Tags: java, logback

I am trying to create a custom Log format for my application. The idea is to create a library with a defined logback.xml where anyone using this library would generate logs in a particular log format (of my POJO where it includes properties instead that POJO of timestamp, level etc, plus a lot more details that are then used to help identify issues)

At the moment I am using Logback and I am creating my own provider to modify the format of the log.

I have a POJO that I want to write into the log in the root of the log, but I cant seem to get it to work. As soon as I give the object a name it works.

```
public class WhatDataJsonProvider extends AbstractFieldJsonProvider<ILoggingEvent> {

  @Override
  public void writeTo(JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, ILoggingEvent event) throws IOException {
    if (event.getArgumentArray().length > 0 && (event.getArgumentArray()[0] instanceof MyObject)) {
      jsonGenerator.writeObject(event.getArgumentArray()[0]);
      // if I use this line instead it works
      //jsonGenerator.writeObjectField("",event.getArgumentArray()[0]);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void prepareForDeferredProcessing(ILoggingEvent event) {
    super.prepareForDeferredProcessing(event);
    event.getCallerData();
  }
}
```

my logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>

<configuration>
  <import class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender"/>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
      <jsonGeneratorDecorator class="net.logstash.logback.decorate.PrettyPrintingJsonGeneratorDecorator"/>
      <providers>
        <mdc/>
        <provider class="com.onewelcome.multitenancy.logging.WhatDataJsonProvider"/>
        </provider>
      </providers>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

When I turn debug on I can see thats its not happy I am not giving it a field name:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Can not start an object, expecting field name (context: Object)
```

I am wondering is there a way to write the object into the root of the JSON blob as I just want the format of the class without a name to it.

**UPDATE**
I did find that I can use [StructuredArguments](https://javadoc.io/static/net.logstash.logback/logstash-logback-encoder/5.1/index.html?net/logstash/logback/argument/StructuredArguments.html) when creating my log e.g.

```
logger.warn("sdfg",fields(pojo));
```

and now this is better as it includes the whole pojo in the log json blob root, but does anyone know how I can modify the values of the pojp e.g. timestamp or log_level in the provider or elsewhere?